# Behavior of error handling of object collections in JSON.NET differs compared to simple types

Tags: c#, json, serialization, error-handling, json.net

I have spent about a day on this. If I have a collection of simple objects like a datetime in json I can properly deserialize it into valid objects and errors. Using the exact same approach for a collection of more complex objects gives me completely different results: the one object with the problem stops all the other objects from being created correctly. I have tried various other methods such as using a JsonTextReader to go through the json looking for objects but it can never get past the bad boolean value 'tru'.

Basically I want to be able to deserialize all the good values and skip the bad values.

I can't find anything in the documentation about this difference in behavior. I also looked at various out stackoverflow articles related to parsing and dealing with errors with no luck. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

In this code you get 3 good datetimes and 3 errors.

```
private void WorkingDeserializer()
{
    List<string> errors = new List<string>();

    List<DateTime> c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DateTime>>(
        @"[
        '2009-09-09T00:00:00Z',
        'I am not a date and will error!',
        [
        1
        ],
        '1977-02-20T00:00:00Z',
        null,
        '2000-12-01T00:00:00Z'
        ]",
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Error = delegate(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args)
            {
                errors.Add(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
                args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
            } 
        });
}
```

In this code you don't get any good values just errors

```
public class FeatureSwitch
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}

private void NonWorkingDeserializer()
{
    List<string> errors = new List<string>();

    List<FeatureSwitch> c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FeatureSwitch>>(
@"[
    {
        'Name': 'TestSwitch1',
        'Description': 'TestSwitch1_Desc',
        'Status': false
    },
    {
        'Name': 'TestSwitch2',
        'Description': 'bad format',
        'Status': tru
    },
    {
        'Name': 'TestSwitch3',
        'Description': 'should be good',
        'Status': true
    }
]", new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Error = delegate(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            errors.Add(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
                       args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are breaking the json serialization with illegal json syntax in the second example. You are not breaking the parsing of date times or models as in the first example.

So the issue is not related to a complex object. If you take that `tru` in the `NonWorkingDeserializer` and put it as one of the value you want to error in your simple date time serializer you will get the same three errors. The three errors in the list of errors have to do with the position of the value `tru`. They do not have to do with the 3 model objects you have in the not working deserializer json string. Even if you try make a json string with 10 of those objects you will get the 3 errors related to the value `tru`

This is because you are trying to deserialize the JSON with broken syntax.

The Boolean value syntax in JSON is as follows:

It includes true or false values.

```
var json-object-name = { string : true/false, .......}
```

you are writing json with the boolean syntax but are not giving a proper value

```
var json-object-name = { string : tru }
```

the syntax for strings is as follows:

```
var json-object-name = { string : "string value"}
```

The syntax for an array is as follows:

```
[ value, .......]
```

The syntax for null is as follows:

```
null
```

the syntax for a number is as follows:

```
var obj = {marks: 97}
```

Those the the different value and their syntax available in Json:

- String
- Number
- Object Array
- TRUE
- FALSE
- NULL

if you make that `tru` a json string `'tru'` you will get the parsing errors that you want, not the broken json syntax error you are getting e.g

```
List<string> errors = new List<string>();

            List<FeatureSwitch> c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FeatureSwitch>>(
        @"[
    {
        'Name': 'TestSwitch1',
        'Description': 'TestSwitch1_Desc',
        'Status': false
    },
    {
        'Name': 'TestSwitch2',
        'Description': 'bad format',
        'Status': 'tru'
    },
    {
        'Name': 'TestSwitch3',
        'Description': 'should be good',
        'Status': true
    }
]", new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Error = delegate (object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args)
            {
                errors.Add(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
                args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
            }
        });
```

This gives you your list of FeatureSwitch with a count of 3 and it gives you a single error because you are not breaking the json itself.

What you are trying to do is like typing a Lorem Ipsum paragraph inside the json  string and dropping a random bit of valid json in there and expecting the deserializer to be able to find your model.

e.g.

```
  List<string> errors = new List<string>();

        List<FeatureSwitch> c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FeatureSwitch>>(
    @"[Maecenas nulla mauris, bibendum ac orci ut, consectetur egestas nisl. Morbi purus nibh, consectetur vel aliquet id, dictum vitae ante. 
    Maecenas cursus nunc orci, quis sollicitudin lorem dictum et. In molestie turpis tortor, eget aliquet nunc finibus sed. Proin vel dui nec eros pretium congue.
    Pellentesque vitae tempor dui. Aliquam molestie,
     {
    'Name': 'TestSwitch1',
    'Description': 'TestSwitch1_Desc',
    'Status': false
     }
    dolor nec gravida molestie, felis neque vestibulum lorem, sed tempus arcu ligula at tortor. 
    Duis ac augue tincidunt odio convallis consectetur. Nam blandit mi ac purus convallis vulputate. Proin eget pretium lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sem ante, gravida et dignissim egestas, commodo tincidunt sapien.]", new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Error = delegate (object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            errors.Add(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
            args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've marked it as answered. I was pointed to jsonlint.com and can see the json is invalid and I will just require valid json as input.